# Check if state is dirty or clean in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have a state that holds a list of items and checkboxes which are either assigned false or true by default (depending on the API I'm working with).

For simplicity let's say that I have my state like this.

```
state = { 
  list: [
    {
    id: 0,
    name: 'item1'
    assigned: true
    }
  ],
   dirtyList: []
}
```

When a checkbox is clicked, you press a button and the popup tells you if the item was registered or removed (checkbox is true/false). But let's say that you start the page with a checkbox already checked and then you click it two times (making it checked true again), the popup should not say that the item has been registered because the original state hasn't changed. (It went from `true`, `false`, then back to `true`)

Here is my checkbox handleChange function

```
checkboxChanged = (event, id) => {    
let isChecked = event.target.checked
const index = this.state.list.findIndex(list => list.id === id)
const newState = [...this.state.list]
let newList = { ...newState[index] }
console.log(newList) 
// By console logging this, it eventually tells me the previous state of the item that was clicked

newState[index].assigned = isChecked
this.setState({
  list: newState,
})
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how/where I can update the `'dirtyList'` state because only then I can compare the original state with the dirty one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it simpler. Create a startpoint and put that in your state. Mutate only the state and compare it to startState when you need to:

```
const startState = {
    a: true,
    b: false
}
this.state = this.startState;

onSomeAction(){
    if( JSON.stringify(startState) !== JSON.stringify(this.state){ /* ... */}
}
```

[Read this page for Object comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) in Javascript.

---

Alternatively, you can just check on value:

```
onChange(key, evt){
    if( this.state[key] !== this.startState[key] ){ /* ... */ }
    // usage: this.onChange(event, 'a');
}
```

Comment: This is a quick way to do it. But I would recommend using libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer

Answer (score 1):

This is how i checked if the text field is dirty.

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({name: '', dirty: false})
.....
const showError = () {
   return fullName.dirty && isEmpty(fullName.name) //<- lodash isEmpty
}
<TextInput
   ...
   onChangeText={(names) => {setFullName({name: names, dirty: true})}}
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

```
this.setState((state)=>{
   // some code here

   const newState = [...state.list]
   return {
      list: newState
   }
})
```